# Como inserir Access-Control-Allow-Origin no cabeçalho

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap

Prezados estou fazendo uma requisição ajax pelo `JQuery.Ajax()`, para consumir um WS SOAP, o envelope esta Ok porém quando eu faço a chamada recebo no navegador "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

O servidor é um Tomcat 7, li a respeito e alterei o *Web.xml* que esta na pasta conf mais nada disto resultou em sucesso onde eu posso colocar esta informação `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Com o valor: `*`

*Meu Ajax:*

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

 //console.log(soapMessage);

 var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url ,
        data: soapMessage,            
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,  
        contentType: "text/xml",  
        dataType: "xml"
      }).done(function( data,  textStatus, jqXHR ) {

         alert(data);

         var headline = $(data.responseText).text();
         $("#retorno").html(headline);

     });
```

Comment: Coloca dataType: "jsonp" e vê se vai.

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134669/como-proteger-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax/135595#135595) te ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

"Geralmente" este tipo de problema ocorre somente quando estamos desenvolvendo localmente, devido aspectos de segurança dos browsers, para evitar e agilizar utilizo este plugin no Chrome http://bit.ly/1E0dpeU.

Para um maior entendimento sobre CORS recomendo este vídeo:
https://www.eventials.com/Globalcode/seguranca-na-web/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: ajudouuuuuuu! sim!!!!  brigadinha !!!

Comment: Foi sucesso pra mim também!