# Submeter formulário para um script php e abrir um modal assim que for enviado

Tags: php, jquery, formulário, modal

Tenho um formulário que já faz a validação dos campos, porém queria que ao clicar no botão enviar ele enviasse os dados para o arquivo `recebe.php` e já abrisse um modal que eu criei.

Segue o código do meu formulário:

```
<form class="tab-pane transition scale fade in active " id="meuFormulario" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="painel/recebe.php">              
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Seu nome completo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeCliente" placeholder="Seu nome completo"  required="">
        <span class="error-label"></span>
        <span class="valid-label"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fd_name" class="sr-only">Nome da loja/assistência</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="fd_name" placeholder="Nome da loja/assistência" required="">
                <span class="error-label"></span>
                <span class="valid-label"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="si_email" class="sr-only">E-mail comercial</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="si_email" placeholder="E-mail comercial"  required="">
                <span class="error-label"></span>
                <span class="valid-label"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="space-top-2x clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                <i class="flaticon-correct7"></i> Enviar
            </button>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signin-page" data-modal-form="sign-in" class="nav-link">Sign In</a>
        </div>
</form>
```

Grato

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow, faça nosso tuor para prosseguir no uso da comunidade. **Ps.:** Identando o código para editar a pergunta e deixa-la mais apresentável eu percebi que está faltando o fechamento da `<div class="row">`

Comment: Pode colocar o código do modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que resultado esperado pode vir com AJAX, não entendi muito bem a dúvida, e nem tem o código do modal mas vou exemplificar.

Ao dar `submit` no formulário você enviará um `ajax` para o recebe.php e após coletar os dados recebidos irá exibir o modal. Isso com JQuery:

```
// ao dubmeter formulário
$('#myForm').submit(function()
{
    // AJAX faz requisição no script, caso nunca usou ajax, saiba
    // que ele aguada um retorno do PHP, seja um echo ou algo assim
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: pagina, // script PHP
        type: 'POST ou GET', // metodo (caso tenha de enviar dados ao script)
        data:  seus-dados, // dados a enviar, caso tenha
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data", // caso for enviar arquivo
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            // se houve sucesso ao contatar pagina php ou coletar retorno
            // a variavel data é o seu retorno do PHP
            // aqui você irá exibir o MODAL
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            // Em caso de erro
        }          
    });
});
```

**PS.:** acho que com isso já dá para responder a pergunta, mas se quiser um exemplo posso elaborar um rapidamente. Vou ver se acho exemplo disso em outras respostas minhas.

Pode ver nessa pergunta um exemplo de ajax enviando dados e executando ação após o formulário ser submetido: [Converter codigo php para responder ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139731/converter-codigo-php-para-responder-ajax/139755#139755)

Como foi pedido, aqui está um exemplo simples, onde tenho um formulário com o campo de mensagem, e ao submeter esse formulário eu envio o dado dele para um script php, nesse php eu apenas valido o dado, vendo se ele tem mais de 3 caracteres, se tiver mais de 3 caracteres é retornada a mensagem digitada e assim ela é exibida no modal, caso tenha menos ou 3 caracteres, então é retornado uma mensagem de falha que faz um texto de erro ser exibido na tela.

A estrutura de arquivos do exemplo é:

```
raiz
- index.php
- script.php
- jquery.min.js
- bootstrap/
----- css/...
----- fonts/...
----- js/...
```

O **index.php**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='uft-8' />
        <title>Example Modal AJAX</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class='form form-inline' id='myForm' method='post'>
            <label>Message:</label>
            <input name='msg' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Digit your message' />

            <input class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' type='submit' value='Send' />
        </form>
        <h4 class='text-danger' id='myError'>Failure, check your message</h4>

        <div id='myModal' class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-success">Message was received!</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body text-success">
                        <p>Your message: <span id='myMsg'></span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

        <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(function()
            {
                $('#myError').hide();
                $('#myForm').submit(function(e)
                {

                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        url: 'script.php', 
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:  new FormData(this),
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData:false,
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                        {
                            if(data != "fail")
                            {
                                $('#myMsg').text(data);
                                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#myError').show('slow');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                        {
                        }          
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

É uma página simples, onde tenho um formulário, uma mensagem de texto e um modal. No script do *JQuery*, a mensagem de erro é ocultada, e quando o formulário for submetido, envio os dados dele para meu script php, caso o retorno seja diferente da string `fail`, eu exibo meu modal, se não exibo meu texto de erro.

No **script.php**:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['msg']) and mb_strlen($_POST['msg']) > 3)
        echo $_POST['msg'];
    else
        echo 'fail';
```

Faço apenas uma validação, para verificar se os dois caminhos estão funcionando.

Comment: Obrigado, se puder me mandar um modelinho seria ótimo, não entendo muito de js, então pra mim será melhor. vlw

Comment: Estou colocando na resposta

Comment: @HudsonVicentim, a resposta foi atualizada com o exemplo, espero que resolva o problema.

Comment: @Ivcs perfeito, obrigado pela resposta e dedicação ao post ;)