# Segurança requisição AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Sabem como posso obter mais segurança ao enviar os dados via AJAX?

Como os dados serão enviados pelo cliente, quero evitar fraude, etc..

Hoje posso a seguinte função:

```
console.log("funcoes lancamento");
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_gerar_boleto').on('click', function(){
        console.log("gerando boleto");      
        var banco = 'itau';
        var boleto = {
            'dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento': 0,
            'taxa_boleto'                 : 0,

        'cedente' : {
            'nome'          : $('#nome').val(),
            'cpf_cnpj'      : $('#cpf_cnpj').val(),
            'agencia'       : $('#agencia').val(),
            'conta'         : $('#conta').val(),
            'conta_cedente' : $('#conta_cedente').val(),
            'carteira'      : $('#carteira').val(),
            'nosso_numero'  : $('#nosso_numero').val(),
            'endereco'      : $('#endereco').val(),
            'cidade'        : $('#cidade').val(),
            'uf'            : $('#uf').val(),   
        },          
        'pedido' : {
            'nome'            : $('#nome_pedido').val(),
            'quantidade'      : $('#quantidade').val(),
            'valor_unitario'  : $('#valor_unitario').val(),
            'data_vencimento' : $('#data_vencimento').val(),
            'numero'          : $('#numero').val(),
            'aceite'          : $('#aceite').val(),
            'especie'         : $('#especie').val(),
            'especie_doc'     : $('#especie_doc').val(),
        },
        'sacado' : {
            'nome'    : $('#nome_sacado').val(),
            'endereco': $('#endereco').val(),
            'cidade'  : $('#cidade').val(),
            'uf'      : $('#uf').val(),
            'cep'     : $('#cep').val(),
        },
        'instrucoes' :{
            'linha1' : '<br>- Sr. Caixa, cobrar multa de 2% após o vencimento',
            'linha2' : '- Receber até 2 dias após o vencimento',    
            'linha3' : '- Em caso de dúvidas entre em contato conosco: atendimento@icob.com.br',
            'linha4' : '',          
        },

        // Informações necessárias que são específicas do Banco do Brasil
        'variacao_carteira'           : '019',
        'contrato'                    : 999999,
        'convenio'                    : 7777777,
        }
        $.ajax({                                    
            url:"boleto_controller",            
            type: "POST",           
            data: {banco: banco, boleto: boleto},
            success: function(data){
                var newWindow = window.open();
                newWindow.document.write(data);             

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Erro...!!');
            }
        });     
    }); 
});
```

Comment: A pergunta [Como proteger uma requisição AJAX?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134669/como-proteger-uma-requisição-ajax) não sanou suas dúvidas? Então acho melhor você [edit] a pergunta e descrever melhor que tipo de segurança você espera melhorar.

Comment: Não sanou!
Eu quero evitar fraude no envio dos dados e não compreendi a outra questão.

Comment: Que tipo de fraude você acha que os usuários podem fazer com este código?

Comment: Vou ser sincero, pois tudo que vou fazer, sou orientado a fazer pelo server-side, uma vez que o sistema fica vulnerável se certas informações serem passadas por client-side.

Inserção de dados, etc...

Então eu pretendo saber se há risco eu enviar desta forma, se sim, como posso proteger os dados.