# Ajax e Update PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, sql-update

Estou tendo um problema para editar os valores do banco de dados. Meu codigo Script:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#salvar_pedido', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td#id').html();
    var nome = $(this).closest('tr').find('td#nome').html();
    var email = $(this).closest('tr').find('td#email').html();
    var celular = $(this).closest('tr').find('td#celular').html();
    var qtd = $(this).closest('tr').find('td#qtd').html();
    var cor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td#cor').html();
    var tam = $(this).closest('tr').find('td#tam').html();     
    var pag = $(this).closest('tr').find('td select#pagamento option:selected').val();        

    $.ajax({
        type      : 'POST', 
        url       : 'editar_pedido.php', 
        data      : {nome: nome, email: email, celular: celular, tam: tam, cor: cor, qtd: qtd, pag: pag}
    }).done(function(resp){
        alert("Alterado !");
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, resp){
        alert('Erro ao alterar '+ resp);
    }); 
});});
```

E meu PHP:

```
$host= '';
$bd= '';
$userbd = ''; 
$senhabd= '';

error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);

$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $userbd, $senhabd, $bd);
mysqli_set_charset($conexao,"utf8");

    $id = $_POST ["id"];  
    $nome = $_POST ["nome"];  
    $email  = $_POST ["email"];   
    $celular  = $_POST ["celular"];   
    $tam  = $_POST ["tam"]; 
    $cor  = $_POST ["cor"]; 
    $qtd = $_POST ["qtd"]; 
    $pag = $_POST ["pag"]; 
    $dahr = strftime('%d de %B de %Y'); 
    mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE pedidos SET nome='$nome', email='$email', cel='$celular', tam='$tam', cor='$cor', qtd='$qtd', dahr='$dahr', pag='$pag' WHERE ID='$id'");
    mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Mas não altera, mas se eu declarar os valores no PHP ele faz a alteração. Tem algum erro que não estou vendo?

Comment: O melhor é mesmo fazer o `echo` da query que está a ser executada antes de ser executada, para você poder ver a query e executa-la manualmente na base de dados. Isso deve ser o suficiente para perceber o erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ser sincero teu código esta mau, vulnerável a *sql injection*, sem verificação nos índices do **POST** usando **closest**.

Antes de mais aconselhava usares [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ou [MYSQLI](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Tenta guardar os teus dados num elemento *hidden* um breve exemplo:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pedidoID" value="'. $pedidoID. '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pedidoName" value="'. $pedidoNome. '">';

[.. etc ..]
```

No teu **JQUERY** tenta captura-los desta forma:

```
$('input[name=pedidoID]').val();
$('input[name=pedidoName]').val();
```

Verifica no **PHP** se os Índices existem e filtra-os exemplo:

```
$produtoName= if(isset($_POST['produtoName'])) ? filter_var($_POST['produtoName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : NULL;

$produtoCor = if(isset($_POST['produtoCor'])) ? filter_var($_POST['produtoCor'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : NULL;
```

### Extra

proteja sempre as suas paginas ajax pois não deves confiar no utilizador
[**LER MAIS**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/135420/70554).

Comment: Obrigao pelas dicas, só estou fazendo teste, esse nao é codigo final, apenas para testar. Mas encontrei o problema, o data do ajax esqueci de informar o id. Agradecido.